# Can Visual Studio Shortcuts be configured on gaming mice?

Tags: visual-studio, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

Can I use the buttons on a gaming mouse for visual studio shortcuts?

For example, I want to configure them for build, rebuild, copy, paste, etc.

To be specific I am about to buy a [Logitech G600 mouse](http://gaming.logitech.com/en-in/product/g600-mmo-gaming-mouse).

Comment: Logitech's software allows any keystroke to be mapped to any mouse button.  I have a mouse and keyboard with Visual Studio macros and have been very happy with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thinkt that this is doable, If you can simulate keystrokes for the buttons. Check the software that Logitech supplied with your mouse to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes not only can it be done, but you can do it for other IDEs too.
If you work on multiple IDEs, it can be a confusing sometimes when you switch back and forth between the two.

The G600 is great if you set up a generic button template that mirrors your workflorw.
That way even if you switch between languages/IDE your workflow (i.e. button/command locations) remains unchanged.

I have posted in detail here if you're interested to find out more.
https://processwire.com/talk/topic/345-need-a-new-mouse/?page=2&tab=comments#comment-165396

It can be time-consuming to set up all the shortcuts, so if anyone reading this that is interested they can ping me for my profile(s) to take home and edit for use.